# Serial Port Debugging on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, usb, c++, debugging, serial-port

I have a written a C++ program on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` which communicates with a USB2Serial device `/dev/ttyUSB0` . I want to know if the connection parameters are set correctly on this file handle, what would be the best way to figure this on Ubuntu? Windows provides a few GUI software which shows all the information in detail, however I'm yet to find something similar in Ubuntu.
 The ones I have tried so far(`sersniff, grabserial`) shows the data but not the connection and other control parameters such as setting `CTS, DTR, RI` etc. I basically want to see what are the `termios` settings that are getting set on the serial port handle at run time 
TIA!!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to retrieve all the settings by running an strace on the process id. The following command helped:

```
    :~/dos$ sudo strace -p <pid> -t -v -o dump.txt

    pid- process ID of my process
    t - adds a timestamp to the system call trace
    v - expands the termios structure which basically contains the serial port settings, without this flag the structure will be truncated
    o - output the trace to a dump file specified
```

This not only gave me all the setting related information,but also gave me the protocol specifics such as what `IOCTLs (TIOCM_RTS, TIOCM_DSR etc)` Thanks to everyone who helped me out here!

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a simple tool which can help you out.
Checkout [here](https://github.com/gilarus/tud.c). Note: you should use -v option

Answer (score 0):

Could `minicom` be of any help?

> Linux comes with many serial text and gui based serial communication programs. My favorite is minicom - friendly menu driven serial communication program.
>
> minicom Common features / usage
>
> - Setting up a remote serial console
> - Access a computer / server if the LAN is down
> - Connect to embedded Linux / BSD device via null modem cable
> - Connect to Cisco routers for configuration
> - Connect to dump device i.e. device w/o keyboard and mouse
> - Dialing directory with auto-redial
> - Support for UUCP-style lock files on serial devices
> - Separate script language interpreter
> - Capture to file
> - Multiple users with individual configurations

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/connect-soekris-single-board-computer-using-minicom.html

You can easily install it by running `sudo apt-get install minicom`

Comment: as far as I know, minicom can be used to connect to a modem and send text commands to the same. In my case I need something like a wireshark inorder to debug my application to see if it is setting the correct communication properties and sending the right control signals. I have gone through the minicom configurations and did not find a sniff mode in it, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You might find some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469511/sniffing-ioctl-and-serial-port-communication

Answer (score 0):

Use minicom to configure serial port for your need, try this, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Minicom. Minicom is widely used to set up serial port (Ex. ttyUSB0).

Comment: as far as I know, minicom can be used to connect to a modem and send text commands to the same. In my case I need something like a wireshark inorder to debug my application to see if it is setting the correct communication properties and sending the right control signals. I have gone through the minicom configurations and did not find a sniff mode in it, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You may need to use stty -F /dev/ttyXX